# Implementing expandable list using array adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a premade library downloaded from a site to use it in my listview. It's called expandable listview, and I think we all know what that is.

In the XML file listview is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="Hello World"/>

    <!-- this is the button that will trigger sliding of the expandable view -->
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/expandable_toggle_button"
            android:text="More"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- this is the expandable view that is initially hidden and will slide out when the 
more button is pressed -->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/expandable"
        android:background="#000000">

    <!-- put whatever you want in the expandable view -->
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Action A" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Action B"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As we all know, an array list needs the listview to be just textview to work, otherwise it throws exception.

Can some one guide me how these things work on array list?

Comment: I guess you're talking about the custom adapter. Just in case you check this to learn about it:

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html

Comment: thanks alot, wish you put it as answer so i accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom adapter for this. See this [link](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html) for tutorial on how to. :)